# How to protected pages by unauthorized access

Tags: reactjs, axios, authorization, single-page-application

I have a backend in Laravel and Frontend in React. I made login-register system but I want to control access to some pages for guests. I wrote something like this:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("user");
        const user = response.data;

        setMessage(`Hi ${user.name}!`);
      } catch (e) {
        setMessage("You are not logged in!");
      }
    })();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
```

OK, It works, I can add a redirect but this method have a problems:

1. I need to add this code to all protected controller and sometimes I can forget. The best way it will add something like middleware in Laravel for React.
2. I need to send a lot of requests. I need a display avatar and username in nav - send a request and this is only one example.
   My route looks like this:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback="Loading">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <FrontLayout>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            </Routes>
          </FrontLayout>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I thought about using Redux and dispatch the basics information about user. I validate data from users and this information would be display only in frontend but I'm not sure that is good idea and it won't solve my problem with clear protectected pages - for example in file with routing. I use `httponly` cookies.